# Ajax response problem

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm handling a very (VERY) simple ajax error, but I cannot manage to fix it:

I have the following structure:

- \manager\javascript\ajax.js
- \manager\manager.jsp
- \manager\test.jsp

In my ajax.js file I have a VERY simple function (without parameter, to make things easier)

```
function makeAjaxRequest() {
   http.open('get', 'test.jsp');
   http.onreadystatechange = processResponse();
   http.send(null);
}

function processResponse() {

   alert("Ready State: " + http.readyState);

   if(http.readyState == 4){
       var response = http.responseText;
       document.getElementById('ajaxResult').innerHTML = response;       
   }
}
```

And finally, my test.jsp file contains only:

```
<% out.print("JSP result");%>
```

In my manager.jsp I call the function but I receive only one "alert" from the processResponse with readyState = 1...

For sure there is something I'm missing in some step.

Could you help?
Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Lucas.

**EDIT**

For sure in my ajax.js file there is also the function to get a xmlHttpObject.

Comment: This might not be what you are looking for, but you should really think about switching to a JavaScript library (e.g. jQuery). It takes care of everything for you. For example, in jQuery, `$('#ajaxResult').load('test.jsp');` would replace your whole code above.

Comment: Try placing your ajax.js and test.jsp in same folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
http.onreadystatechange = processResponse();
```

Remove the `()` to assign the actual function, not the result of the function.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks a lot! Indeed the problem is that. You have no idea of how many hours I lost trying to solve it. Anyway, how could I pass some parameters to the processResponse function, such as the id of the target field I want the response to be placed in. Should I use global variables?